# Find the fundamental solutions of the following differential operators

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

Find the fundamental solutions of the following differential operators. Check that they satisfy (outside the singularities) the homogeneous equation in principal variables and the conjugate one in dual variables
$$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}+2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y \partial t}+2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial z\partial t}-2\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial y\partial z}$$

**My attempt:**

I thought that in order to find the fundamental solutions, you have to solve the equation
$$\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial t^2}-\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}+2\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y \partial t}+2\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial z\partial t}-2\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial y\partial z}=0$$

It can be seen that the solution will be in the form of separable functions, i.e. $u(x, y, z, t) = X(x)Y(y)Z(z)T(t)$, then

$$\frac{X''}{X}=\frac{Y''}{Y}+2\frac{T'}{T}\frac{Y'}{Y}+2\frac{T'}{T}\frac{Z'}{Z}-2\frac{Y'}{Y}\frac{Z'}{Z}+\frac{T''}{T}$$

*I was able to get to this point, but then I don't know how to solve it. Am I using the right method, is there no simpler method of solving it?*

Comment: I tried the Fourier transform to solve, but we have no boundary conditions and I can't do anything with this integral. Without boundary conditions I cannot find the functions $F_1$ and $F_2$
$u(x,y,z,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }\left ( F_1(k_x,y+z-t)e^{ik_xx}+F_2(k_x,y-z+t)e^{ik_xx} \right )dk_x$

Comment: Your $Y''/Y$ term suggests the original equation ought to have included a $\partial^2/\partial y^2$ term.